# Почему код исполняется неверно?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу простенького ассистента на python, столкнулся с такой проблемой: в коде

```
print(">>> Привет, я Енот, компьютерный ассистент!")

print(">>> Вот что я могу: ")

skills = ('1) Дать прогноз одежды', '2) Напомнить время', '3) Сосчитать выражение (калькулятор).')

for skill in skills:
      print(skill)

act = input()

if not isinstance(act, int):

    print("Упс, похоже ты где-то ошибся, посмотри на мой список команд ещё раз: ")
```

чтобы пользователь не вводил в переменную **act**, всегда исполняется код после первого **if**'a - "Упс, похоже ты где-то ошибся, посмотри на мой список команд ещё раз: " Почему? Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что функция `input` всегда возвращает строку. Проверку на то что внутри введенной строки все символы цифры можно сделать с помощью `act.isnumeric()`.

Answer (score 3):

Что бы вы ни вводили в `input()` на выходе **всегда** строка, т.е. тип `str`, поэтому `int` там никогда нет.

Answer (score 0):

Функция input() возвращает строку, нужно просто поменять тип следующим образом:

```
act = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать `skills` словорем, а проверку с помощью цикла `for` переберите, например так:

```py
for i in skills:
    if act != i:
        print("message")
```